# Cant connect to Mysql by using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to connect into MySQL database by using simple script python but unsuccessful. Below is my code,

```
[root@vn pyceaudio]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'hostname',database = 'testdb',user = 'test',password = 'test1234')
```

But I getting this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 172, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 780, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 200, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
TypeError: function takes at most 14 arguments (15 given)
```

Please advice and show me if I did it wrong. I am really new to Python and still leaning. By the way, I'm using Python2.7 in Centos7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'hostname',database = 'testdb',user = 'test',password = 'test1234')

    if cnx.is_connected()://Runs if connection is established
        db_Info = cnx.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")//executes query using cursor
        record = cursor.fetchone()//fetches first data from above cursor
        print("Your connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if (cnx.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Refer this link : [Python Mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_table.asp) and [Python Mysql connection](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-database-connection/)

Comment: There is also some possibilities that you could have written a function which is conflicting with inbuilt function of MySQL connector, just check for it once.

Comment: i got error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    if (cnx.is_connected()):
NameError: name 'cnx' is not defined

Comment: Then it is possible that the values which you are using to connect may be wrong, such as database, password or username, do check for it.

Comment: And again if it doesn't work I'll recommend you to uninstall mysql.connector and reinstall it.